# Doctine(Symfony) Load Fixtures, reference doesnt exist

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hey guys im working on the Symfony stack with Doctrice ORM, im having issues loading up my app fixtures.
The app is divided in 3 models `User` , `Post` , `Comments`

With 3 functions  `public function loadUser(ObjectManager $manager)` / `public function loadPost(ObjectManager $manager)` /  `public functionloadComments(ObjectManager $manager)`
Two of those have a foreign key table, with loading fixtures on the comments part i get an error on the reference post :

```
$comments->setPost($this->getReference(
                self::POSTS[rand(0, count(self::POSTS) - 1 )]['name']));
```

the error output is   `Reference to "Vacation" does not exist`, but when i load my post using the same method i do not get that error on the reference the cod looks like this :

```
$post->setUser($this->getReference(
                self::USERS[rand(0, count(self::USERS) - 1)]['last_name']));
```

Comment: I don't know what your `$this->getReference()` looks like, but I already find it extremely weird, that it receives the *name* of the post and not just the post object (similarly to users). and maybe that's already the reason ... care to elaborate? ^^

Comment: Well i litteraly just posted what it looks like, i written down the value that i wanted to load, post is a const array on my Appfixtures, name is setup up this way within ['name' => 'Name of post'].

Comment: Post whole fixture classes. Do you load fixtures in correct order? https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-the-fixture-files-in-order

Comment: @blahy Yes i load the user first then the post followed by the comments `
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
       $this->loadUsers($manager);
       $this->loadTheme($manager);
       $this->loadSousThemes($manager);
    }`

Comment: Then maybe you just didnt `addReference` to `Vacation` object?

Comment: @blahy on which part of the code am i suppose to`addRefence`, cause just doing `getReference` on post worked perfectly.

Comment: Search for `addReference` in the documentation i linked above. How doctrine is supposed to know what `Vacation` means? You have to tell it that `Vacation` means one of your objects. You didnt post the source code of your fixtures so it is difficult to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220046/discussion-between-dezz-h-and-blahy).

Comment: @blahy i moved the conversation to the chat to avoid lengthy comments

Comment: Did you load files in right order? https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-the-fixture-files-in-order

Comment: @blahy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508415/doctrine-fixtures-load-having-issue-setting-references-foreign-key-violates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered here with more details on the source code and where the error is generated from :

[Doctrine fixtures load, having issue setting references (foreign key) violates -not-null constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508415/doctrine-fixtures-load-having-issue-setting-references-foreign-key-violates)