# Doctrine fixtures load, having issue setting references (foreign key) violates -not-null constraint

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine Fixtures, to load some data into my database,
There is 3 different tables User, Theme and Sous_Theme, the last two Tables have foreign Keys, Theme as (user.id) and Sous_Theme as two foreign keys (user.id & theme.id)

My `AppFixtures.php` class is set up in a way with having each model value already written in such way :

```
 private const USERS = [
      [
          'last_name' => 'Goodman',
          'first_name'=> 'Robert',
          'email' => 'robert@foobar.com',
          'job' => 'Admin_Tester',
          'password' => 'blablablablablbal',
          'username' => 'blablablabla',
          'roles' => [USER::ROLE_ADMIN]
      ]...
]



private const THEMES =
    [
        ['name' => 'A theme'],
        ['name' => ' A theme 2']
  .....
]

private const SOUSTHEMES = [
    [
        'name' => 'blablabla',
        'part1' => true, //boolean
        ...
    ],
```

Before writting the SOUSTHEMES part i have loaded the Users and Themes values with the reference it worked perfectlty :

```
public function loadTheme(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach (self::THEMES as $themeDate){
            $theme = new Theme();
            $theme->setName($themeDate['name']);
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $date->modify('-'. rand(0, 10) . 'day');
            $theme->setCreatedAt($date);
            //// Setting user Id into our Theme table.
            $theme->setUser($this->getReference(
                self::USERS[rand(0, count(self::USERS) - 1)]['last_name']));
            $manager->persist($theme);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
```

now im trying to load the sousthemes with the references theme.id and user.id :

```
public function loadSousThemes(ObjectManager $manager){
        foreach (self::SOUSTHEMES as $sousthemeData){
            $sousthemes = new SousTheme();
            $sousthemes->setName($sousthemeData['name']);
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $date->modify('-'. rand(0, 10) . 'day');
            $sousthemes->setCreatedAt($date);
   

            //// Setting boolean values
            $sousthemes->setPart1($sousthemeData['part_n1']);
  $sousthemes->setUsername($this->setReference(
                self::USERS[rand(0, count(self::USERS) - 1)]['last_name'], $sousthemes));
            $sousthemes->setTheme($this->setReference(
                self::THEMES[rand(0, count(self::THEMES) - 1)]['name'], $sousthemes));

            $manager->persist($sousthemes);
        }
        $manager->flush();
```

I have started with the `getReference()` method but i got the ref doesnt exist so i switched to the `addReference()` i got another error saying the ref already exist that i need to use the `setReference()` to override it so i changed my method to `setReference()` now i get an error

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "theme_id" violates not-null constraint
```

i get the same error on `user.id` too.
The `getReference` worked perfectly on when i added the user.id value to my theme but it isnt working on for southeme i'm trying to figure out why, is it because i'm injecting two foreign keys which is something i highly doubt, i dont know what i'm missing and before anybody says it lol Yeah i'm loading up my values in the right order user first then theme followed by sousthemes :

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->loadUsers($manager);
       $this->loadTheme($manager);
       $this->loadSousThemes($manager);
    }
```

here is the UploadUsers function :

```
public function loadUsers(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach (self::USERS as $userData)
        {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFirstName($userData['first_name']);
            $user->setLastName($userData['last_name']);
            $user->setEmail($userData['email']);
            $user->setJob($userData['job']);
            $user->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->
            encodePassword($user, $userData['password']));
            $user->setUsername($userData['username']);
            $user->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $user->setRoles($userData['roles']);
            $this->addReference($userData['last_name'], $user);
            $manager->persist($user);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
```

Comment: show also loadUsers method. in your loadSousThemes those should definitely be getReference methods used,not setReference.

Comment: @blahy just added the loaduser function yeah i know its suppose to be getReference but i get a reference when i use that method and i get an sqlite error on null constraint when i use the setReference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you dont need addReference/getReference at all, because you use one fixture file. So in your case you can just save the objects and use them in setters, for example:

```
in loadUsers:

public function loadUsers(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach (self::USERS as $userData)
        {
            $user = new User();
            ///...
            $manager->persist($user);

            $this->users[$userData['username']] = $user;
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }

and in loadTheme:

$theme->setUser($this->users[self::USERS[rand(0, count(self::USERS) - 1)]['username']]);
```

You dont need references, because you have access to objects, references are useful when fixtures are in separate files, because then you dont have access to the objects created in different fixture files.
It is described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures .

But lets say you want to use references and I will try to give pointers that will fix the code you already have. You say loading users by reference worked on themes:

```
$theme->setUser($this->getReference(self::USERS[rand(0, count(self::USERS) - 1)]['last_name']));
```

It works because you added the reference in `loadUsers`:

```
$this->addReference($userData['last_name'], $user);
```

So after `loadUsers` you have those references available:

```
User objects:
 - Goodman
 - ...
```

Now whenever you call `$this->getReference('Goodman');` you will get the User object that you can use in setters, ex. setUser();

But you never called `addReference` in `loadTheme` to save references to your theme objects.

Add `addReference` to `loadTheme`:

```
public function loadTheme(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach (self::THEMES as $themeDate){
            $theme = new Theme();
            $theme->setName($themeDate['name']);
            // ...
            $theme->setUser($this->getReference(
                self::USERS[rand(0, count(self::USERS) - 1)]['last_name']));
            $manager->persist($theme);

            $this->addReference($theme->getName(), $theme);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
```

So after `loadUsers` and `loadThemes` those references will be available:

```
User objects:
 - Goodman
 - ...

Theme objects:
 - A theme
 - A theme 2
 - ...
```

And finally in your `loadSousThemes`:

```
$sousthemes->setUsername($this->getReference(
                self::USERS[rand(0, count(self::USERS) - 1)]['last_name']));
            $sousthemes->setTheme($this->getReference(
                self::THEMES[rand(0, count(self::THEMES) - 1)]['name']));
```

Note that I assume that `$sousthemes->setUsername()` is really for setting User object, not just username (why it is not called setUser?)

Comment: Thanks! yea i just realized using the addreference method needed to be applied to themeloader. makes more sense now